# dividing input file into multiple files based on one of the column

Tags: java, string, file

I have a semicolon delimited input file where first column is a 3 char fixed width code, while the remaining columns are some string data.

```
001;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
001;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
002;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
003;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
001;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
003;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
001;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
002;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
002;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
003;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
003;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
003;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
002;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
001;first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
```

I want to divide above file into number of files based on different values of first column.

For e.g. in above example, there are three different values in the first column, so I will divide the file into three files viz. 001.txt, 002.txt, 003.txt

The output file should contain item count as line one and data as remaining lines.

So there are 5 001 rows, so 001.txt will be:

```
5
first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
first_data_str;second_data_str;third_data_str;fourth_data_str
```

Similarly, 002 file will have first line as 4 and then 4 lines of data and 003 file will have first line as 5 and then five lines of data.

What would be the most efficient way to achieve this considering very large input file with **greater then 100,000 rows**?

I have written below code to read lines from the file:

```
try{
          FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(this.inputFilePath);
          DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
          String strLine;

          while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
              String[] tokens = strLine.split(";");
         }

          in.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered having one reader and three writers, read in one line and write it to the appropriate writer? KIS http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Comment: @AnthonyGrist, 100 thousand or 0.1 million is a lakh.

Comment: @JohnB: You are assuming that there would be only 3 writers. But the answer to question "how many writers" would be answered only once I have read the whole file which will give me a set of tokens[0] i.e. the number of output files I will have to make.

Comment: Seems like a small enough file to read in the entire data and split it into multiple lists based on the tag. Is that correct, or do you need to keep only a small amount of the file in memory at a time?

Comment: Can 001.txt file contain "000005" instead of "5" as its first (count) line? What is the typical length of data line, to know overall amount of required memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, create `HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map` to collect all the data from the file.
Second, use `strLine.split(";",2)` instead of `strLine.split(";")`. The result will be array of length 2, first element be the code and the second the data.
Then, add decoded string to the map:

```
ArrayList<String> list=map.get(tokens[0]);
if (list==null) {
   map.put(tokens[0], list=new ArrayList<String>();
}
list.add(tokens[1]);
```

At the end, scan the `map.keySet()` and for each key, create a file named as that key and write list's size and list's content to it.

Comment: in case of large file - OOE will be easily observed

Answer (score 1):

- for each line
- extract chunk name, e.g 001
- look for file named "001-tmp.txt"
- if one exist, read first line - it will give you number of lines, then increment the value and write into same file using [seek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#seek(long)) function with argument 0 and then use [writeUTF](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html#writeUTF(java.lang.String)) to override the string. Perhaps some string length calculation has to be applied here, leave placeholder for 10 spaces for example.
- if one does not exist, then create one and write 1 as first line, padded with 10 spaces
- append current line to the file
- close current file
- proceed with next line of source file

Comment: Is it possible to do the seek in an open writer and maintain a collection of open files as was suggested by @sharadendu?

Comment: no, seek does not work with writers AFAIK. Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html for details

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions that comes to mind is to keep a 'Map' and only open every file once. But you wont be able to this because you have around 1 lac rows, so no OS will allow you that many open file descriptors.

So one of the way is to open the file in append mode and keep writing to it and closing it. But because the of huge many file open close calls , the process may slow up. You can test it for your self though.

If the above is not providing satisfying results, you may try a mix of approach 1 and 2, where by you only open 100 open files at any time and only closing a file if a new file that is not already opened needs to be written to....

Comment: How do you solve the line count at the beginning of the file if using mechanism 2?

Comment: you read each line and check the first column and open the appropriate  file using FileWriter(name, append) and write to it . hope it answers , or am i missing something ...

Comment: You were referring to keeping files open. How do you update the first line of a file that is open? See jdevelop's answer.

Comment: You don't need to do those calculations on your own, if you open the file in append mode. For example if use the the following code snippent PrintWriter fw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("append"), true)); 
  fw.println("ABC");
  fw.close();
  
  fw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("append"), true));
  fw.println("PQR");
  fw.close();                 You will get file like "ABC" + "\n" + "PQR"

Answer (score 0):

For each three character code, you're going to have a list of input lines. To me the obvious solution would be to use a `Map`, with `String` keys (your three character codes) pointing to the corresponding `List` that contains all of the lines.

For each of those keys, you'd create a file with the relevant name, the first line would be the size of the list, and then you'd iterate over it to write the remaining lines.

Comment: FYI, Guava has a MultiMap collection that implement Map<T, List<V>>

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are not fixed to three files so I suggest you create a map of writers with your three characters code as key and the writer as value.

For each line you read, you select or create the required reader and write the lines into. Also you need a second map to maintain the line count values for all files.

Once you are done with reading the source file, you flush and close all writers and read the files one by one again. This time you just add the line count in front of the file. There is no other way but to rewrite the entire file to my knowledge because its not directly possible to add anything to the beginning of a file without buffering and rewriting the entire file. I suggest you use a temporary file for this one.

This answer applies only in case you file is too large to be stored fully in memory. In case storing is possible, there are faster solutions to this. Like storing the contents of the file fully in `StringBuffer` objects before writing it to files.

Comment: This assumes that it will be possible to maintain the number of open file handles. This alg could result in 1001 concurrently open files.

Comment: In case you hit this limit as well you always have the option of opening and closing the files every time you need to add a line. Then you only have two active file handles. In this case you only need to maintain a list of files you already accessed in order to write the line numbers thing afterwards.